# What network protocols does a Postgres database server use?

Tags: iptables, postgresql, database, protocols

I have a postgres 9.1 server running on the default port 5432 on an Ubuntu 12.04 cloud server.

I want to open up the port, so I can make remote queries -- but I have to open the port on IP tables, which requires that I specify a protocol. [This doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/protocol-flow.html) does not mention TCP/UDP, etc.

What protocol should I permit in IP tables?

Comment: Don't forget to enable SSL... http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ssl-tcp.html

Answer (score 23):

The protocol is plain TCP/IP.

From posgresql documentation about ["frontends" and "backends" protocol](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol.html):

> PostgreSQL uses a message-based protocol for communication between frontends and backends (clients and servers). The protocol is supported over **TCP/IP** and also over Unix-domain sockets. **Port number 5432** has been registered with IANA as the customary TCP port number for servers supporting this protocol, but in practice any non-privileged port number can be used.

So regarding *iptables* use the `tcp` protocol, as Unix-domain socket are not meant to be used over network.

*iptables* example:

```
iptables <other_options> -p tcp -dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```

**Note**:

As pointed out by *Lekensteyn*, it is especially wise to consider activating SSL over that network connection (see postgresql documentation regarding [using TCP-over-SSL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ssl-tcp.html)). The *iptables* rule would not change in that case: same port (5432), same protocol (tcp).

Answer (score 1):

By default PostgreSQLt listen on TCP port 5432. Use the following iptables rules allows incoming client request (open port 5432).

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j ACCEPT
```

Where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the IP of the server you're connecting from so you're not opening postgres up to the world.

Answer (score 0):

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j ACCEPT
```

Will this command change the pg_hba  ?